# Problems with databricks dbfs : Put API

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I am doing a small project in databricks for my exam, where i am having some data getting sent to the api and then transfroming it with delta live tables. Im currently struggling with the api as i need to use that to put some Json in the dbfs. i am usin the  /api/2.0/dbfs/put command found here: https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/dbfs/put.

So far i've tried putting the Json data in the content attribute but am getting various errors on that. But it also says that if the content attrbute is missing it will use a posted file instead, but doesnt explain further than that. Anyone have any experience with the api that might have some helpfull comments?

Comment: From that doc if you want to pass it as a string it looks like you need to convert it to BASE64

Answer (score 0):

The content should be specified as base64 encoded string - from the API docs:

> Alternatively you can pass contents as base64 string.

But really you need to use [Databricks Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/) instead - you will be able to upload big files (the `put` method is limited to 1Mb), it will handle authentication, etc. Here is [an example](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sdk-py/blob/main/examples/dbfs/download_file.py) from the `examples` folder of the SDK repository that uploads a file, and then downloads it:

```py
import io
import pathlib
import time

from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient

w = WorkspaceClient()

root = pathlib.Path(f'/tmp/{time.time_ns()}')

f = io.BytesIO(b"some text data")
w.dbfs.upload(f'{root}/01', f)

with w.dbfs.download(f'{root}/01') as f:
    assert f.read() == b"some text data"
```